# How to clear the added rows from a datagridview binded using a BindingSource c# .net

Tags: c#, datagridview, reset, bindingsource, strongly-typed-dataset

Its a Windows Form Application. 
Database is MS Access.
Using Typed DataSet.
I am having a datagridview, which i only use to insert data into database.
I want to clear all the rows added as soon as I click on Reset Button on my form.
The datagridview is using bindingSource. The Binding Source is using a Typed DataTable from the Typed DataSet

Comment: Are you looking for [DataTable.RejectChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rejectchanges(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You probably want the code in your question. Or is that the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following scenario

```
this.dataGridViewPurDetails.DataSource = this.purchaseDetailBindingSource; 
// purchaseDetailBindingSource 
// this.purchaseDetailBindingSource.DataMember = "PurchaseDetail";
this.purchaseDetailBindingSource.DataSource = this.tVDataSet;
```

This Solution Worked
    //Clear All the rows from the datagridview

```
BindingSource DT = (BindingSource)dataGridViewPurDetails.DataSource; 
if (DT != null) 
    ((TVDataSet)DT.DataSource).PurchaseDetail.Clear();
```